# Checking Salesforce from SFMC query to see if date field is null not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a query in Marketing Cloud that is checking a field in Salesforce to see if it's null. The field I'm looking at is a date field. It does not seem to be working. How would I check to see if a datefield is empty? Does NULL not work? Do I need to check for length? Or to see if it's greater than today? I don't like that because it just doesn't feel right.

Comment: 1900-01-01 is a default value sql server puts in for you because Date datatype cannot have an empty value. have you checked if this works: isnull(@SalesforceField, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')

Comment: Where does your Salesforce data reside?  The Salesforce data would need to by pushed to Data Extension via import or data sync, before it could be queries using a Marketing Cloud tools.

Comment: @DavidDevoy everything is linked up already. connector is in place and the field is available.

Comment: @BoHu I will try that!